# redux-form get the name of form for the input

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

in the field component , there is a way to get the name of form?
I use the same input component for differents forms, actually I use a hardcode form name, but i'd like to find a way to get the name of form that contains the input

```
class FormField extends Component {
    process = () => {
      nameForm= 'myForm'; // hardcode, i'd like to get the form parent
      const values = this.props.myState.form[nameForm].values;

      (...)
    }
    render()
        <input
          {...myInput}
          type={typeInput}
          autoComplete="off"
          processInput={this.process()}
        />

  }


class Form extends Component {

  render() {

    return (

      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div className="appBodyTitleSeparator" />

        <div className="formSection">
          <Field
            name="customer_id"
            component={FormField}
            myState={this.props.myState}

          />
    (...)
}
```

my Form is in another component separated, i'd like not use props to get the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you form you can access the `formName` like `props.form` in your Form component which you can pass as props to the `Field` component.

```
class FormField extends Component {
    process = () => {
      const nameForm = this.props.formName
      const values = this.props.myState.form[nameForm].values;

      (...)
    }
    render()
        <input
          {...myInput}
          type={typeInput}
          autoComplete="off"
          processInput={this.process()}
        />

  }


class Form extends Component {

  render() {
    const {form} = this.props;
    return (

      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div className="appBodyTitleSeparator" />

        <div className="formSection">
          <Field
            name="customer_id"
            formName={form}
            component={FormField}
            myState={this.props.myState}

          />
    (...)
}
```

See this **[example](https://codesandbox.io/s/n0x3v598o0)**

Comment: sorry I was not clear, i have two separeted components, i've tried to copy most of code in my updated question